# Undefined control sequence error with mhchem and hyperref, \ce within \section{}

Tags: hyperref, pandoc, mhchem

I get an "undefined control sequence" error when trying to use the mhchem and
hyperref packages together, when `\ce` is within a `\section{}` label. A minimum example that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{\ce{H2O}}
\end{document}
```

The error message using pdflatex in MikTeX 2.9 on Windows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\mhchem@ce ...ate {s}\chardef \mhchem@ce@substate
                                                  =0\relax \mhchem@ce@result...
l.5 \section{\ce{H2O}}
```

I'm very new to mhchem, and latex in general -- is this a known problem? Is
there a workaround? (As background, I first encountered this problem trying to use \ce within
a markdown file and then make a pdf with pandoc. The template.latex file for
pandoc adds `\usepackage{hyperref}` when using pdflatex.)

Comment: I think it's the fact that `hyperref` tries to add a bookmark with content `\ce{H2O}` and this will (probably fail)

Comment: Does `\section{\texorpdfstring{\ce{H2O}}{H2O}}` help?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That fixes it, thank you! Thanks for explaining what's going on, too.

Comment: See Heiko Oberdiek's full and much better answer ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\ce` breaks in the code that tries to convert it to a bookmark string.
With `\texorpdfstring` an alternative can be provided for the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{\ce{H2O}}{H\texttwoinferior O}}
\end{document}
```

In this case you are lucky, that there is a subscript 2 in Unicode (enabled
by option `unicode` or `pdfencoding=auto`).

Also `\ce` can be disabled for bookmarks to print its argument at least:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\ce\@firstofone}% after hyperref is loaded
```

Package `bookmarks` improves the algorithm for the bookmarks, that makes an additional LaTeX run obsolete in most cases. Also it adds more features.

### Math example from the comments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{numbered,open}
\begin{document}
\section{Water \texorpdfstring{\ce{H2O}}{H\texttwoinferior O}}
\section{Implication of \texorpdfstring{$E=mc^2$}{E = mc\twosuperior}}
\section{Solutions of \texorpdfstring
  {$\ddot s = -\omega^2 s$}%
  {\"s = \textminus\omega\twosuperior s}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with math]

Comment: Off-topic comment: Is there any hope that PDF and the readers/viewers will understand accept math typesetting in bookmarks?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer And who wants to read a PDF, where the math also pollutes the section titles? Having complicated math expressions in the title is not quite inviting to read the section.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I like the unicode subscript 2.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I don't want huge math expressions in section titles (or generic bookmarks), but something like inline intermixture, i.e. `Implications of E=mc^2` or Solutions of `\ddot{s} = -\omega^2 s`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer These math examples can be expressed in Unicode, see updated answer.